# SSL certificate error: multiple browsers (IE/Chrome/Firefox) and both computers on LAN (Mac & PC) affected

Tags: ssl-certificate, security-warning

Both my Mac and PC (on my home network) are giving me the following error when attempting to log in to Microsoft SSL sites from my home network:

[image]

I have tried logging in to another computer on a different network (using LogMeIn) to access the same SSL sites and do not see the error (tested in Firefox).

There are no proxy servers or unusual DNS settings. I've scanned my PC for Malware but it came back clean. The time and date on my systems is correct. This just started happening today.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I'm using a DNS server from my ISP which was assigned when I used to have a static IP address.

Comment: the keychain solution fixed this on mac, see here:

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266918/multiple-ssl-errors-after-upgrading-to-os-x-10-9-4-in-chrome-and-safari